# How do I get an SPFolder from the UniqueID?

Tags: development, feature

I have the Unique ID for an SPFolder object. I also have the SiteID that it is located at. How can I (in C# from a SharePoint feature) get this item starting from the Site? Is there a way to do it without knowing the SPList it is in and without iterating all the lists? There is a related issue, it is possible that the unique ID I have is for a root SPList not an SPFolder in the list. It appears the only way I can check that is to try to get the list and if it throws an exception then I know it is a folder. Any help along these lines would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using SPWeb.GetFolder(Guid) method. SPList itself is not derived from SPFolder so I dont believe you should have any "related issue" that you mentioned.

Comment: My "related issue" is that I don't specifically know that the ID is an SPFolder, it is either an SPFolder or an SPList object for the site.

Comment: I think you would then have to depend on try..error..tryagain approach or figure out a way to know what kind of object the guid represents.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured I would have to do the try/catch to handle the situation. I totally had missed the GetFolder method, don't know how I missed that being there. Thanks for the help!